# Can a function be extended in Bash?

Tags: bash

If I define a function in a file, say **test1.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash

foo() {
    echo "foo"
}
```

And in a second, **test2.sh**, I try to redefine `foo`:

```
#!/bin/bash

source /path/to/test1.sh    
...
foo() {
    ...
    echo "bar"
}
foo
```

Is there a way to change **test2.sh** to produce:

```
foo
bar
```

I know it is possible to do with Bash built-ins using `command`, but I want to know if it is possible to extend a user function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I see the need to do something like this. You can use functions inside of functions, so why reuse the name when you can just call the original sourced function in a newly created function like this:

```
AirBoxOmega:stack d$ cat source.file
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

foo() {
    echo "foo"
}
AirBoxOmega:stack d$ cat subfoo.sh
#!/usr/local/bin/bash


source /Users/d/stack/source.file
sub_foo() {
  foo
  echo "bar"
}

sub_foo
AirBoxOmega:stack d$ ./subfoo.sh
foo
bar
```

Of course if you REALLY have your heart set on modifying, you could source your function inside the new function, call it, and then do something esle after, like this:

```
AirBoxOmega:stack d$ cat source.file
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

foo() {
    echo "foo"
}
AirBoxOmega:stack d$ cat modify.sh
#!/usr/local/bin/bash


foo() {
  source /Users/d/stack/source.file
  foo
  echo "bar"
}

foo
AirBoxOmega:stack d$ ./modify.sh
foo
bar
```

Comment: I've come across this situation when I want to extend the functionality of something in a sourced file which in turn is used in other functions sourced.  I think you hit the money though in overwriting `foo` directly in the second `foo`'s namespace. Thanks!

Comment: This way does give errors, however, if you have readonly variables in the sourced file, but it might be something I can live with. =)

Comment: I don't really see that as extending of the function. You just used another function with a different name. Also after `source`, your original function gets overridden. One way is to use a subshell but subshells don't affect the environment of the caller.

Comment: You can probably squelch the errors by adding 2> /dev/null at the end of the source command. Of course, if those errors point to something that's going to break things, that's bad...but if not, no biggie. 
@konsolebox - To which section of my code do you refer? I did it two ways, one of which involved creating a second different function, and one that involves sourcing from within the function (which I think is silly, but seems to do the trick)

Comment: @DarrellFx This is what I mean: http://pastebin.com/59tzFLZ0. In the end the function didn't get to extend itself. The extended instance is only usable once. You can wrap-up functionalities inside a file like Ruby modules but that's going to be ugly as it keeps sourcing a file for every call. Base: `foo() { . foo.sh; }`. Extension: `foo() { . foo.sh; . foo_ext.sh; }`.

Comment: About your first answer, yeah I guess you were suggesting not to extend the function but to use another function with a different name that would call the former function. So I guess it's ok.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know of a nice way of doing it (but I'd love to be proven wrong).

Here's an ugly way:

```
# test2.sh
# ..
eval 'foo() {
        '"$(declare -f foo | tail -n+2)"'

        echo bar
      }'
```

Comment: There's an well known, old saying I just made up: "There's ugly, and there's obscene. Ugly can be an art, obscene is just obscene. Shell scripting is ugly, using eval obscene." (Still love the cleverness)

Comment: This didn't work for me. `declare -f foo | tail -n+3 | head -n-1` did.

Comment: @Oleh: `head -n1` will take the first line of whatever it's input is, which in this case will be just one line of the definition of `foo`. So I don't see how that could do anything useful at all. However, you're right that I used `head` where I should have used `tail`. Fixed, thanks. (By the way, leaving the original braces around the original function definition was deliberate. They do no harm.)

Comment: @rici OK, if they do no harm then I agree that your current solution is better. However do note the `-` in my `head` call. It discards the last line (the brace).

Comment: @oleh: you're right, I did miss the `-`. Sorry. The braces make the existing function body a compound command, which is effectively a no-op in this case.

Comment: Suggest using `grep -v -E -e '\{$' -e '^}'` instead of `tail` and `head` would look like this: `'"$(declare -f foo | grep -v -E -e '\{$' -e '^})"'`

Answer (score 2):

No it's not possible. A new declaration would override the previous instance of a function. But despite not having that capability it's still helpful when you want to disable a function without having to unset it like:

```
foo() {
    :  ## Do nothing.
}
```

It's also helpful with lazy initializations:

```
foo() {
    # Do initializations.
    ...

    # New declaration.
    if <something>; then
        foo() {
            ....
        }
    else
        foo() {
            ....
        }
    fi

    # Call normally.
    foo "$@"
}
```

And if you're brave and capable enough to use `eval`, you can even optimize your function so it would act without additional `if`s based on a condition.

Comment: I see how this might be helpful, but I'm not sure what conditionals I would be using.  It would appear that in the original function I would have to have implemented separate functionality. Is this what you are intending?

Comment: @MrAlias In cases like it. Not really a practice implied to follow :)

Comment: Take a look at my [log.sh](http://sourceforge.net/p/playshell/code/ci/master/tree/source/log.sh) and [exts.sh](http://sourceforge.net/p/playshell/code/ci/master/tree/source/exts.sh).

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the links @konsolebox.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can,

see this page : https://mharrison.org/post/bashfunctionoverride/

```
    save_function() {
        local ORIG_FUNC=$(declare -f $1)
        local NEWNAME_FUNC="$2${ORIG_FUNC#$1}"
        eval "$NEWNAME_FUNC"
    }

    save_function foo old_foo
    foo() {
        initialization_code()
        old_foo()
        cleanup_code()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've written a function to achieve exactly this, somewhat inspired by Python decorators. It's a bit verbose, but I have it in my `.bashrc` and often find it useful:

Somewhat inspired by Python decorators, here's a function I've written to allow wrapping bash functions, built-in commands and calls to executables. I have it in my .bashrc file.

```bash
# bashwrap function: given a function name and code to run before and/or after,
# wrap the existing function with the code that comes before and after.  The
# before and after code is taken literally and eval'd, so it can do things like
# access "$@" and indeed change "$@" by using shift or set or similar.
bashwrap () {
    local command beforecode aftercode type unset_extglob n
    local innerfuncname innerfunccode
    local -n varname

    command="$1"
    beforecode="$2"
    aftercode="$3"

    # Check the current state of extglob: this code needs it to be set,
    # but it should be reset to avoid unexpected changes to the global
    # envirnoment.
    if ! shopt -q extglob; then
        unset_extglob=YesPlease
        shopt -s extglob
    fi

    # Tidy the before and after code: trim whitespace from the start and end,
    # and make sure they end with a single semicolon.
    for varname in beforecode aftercode; do
        varname="${varname##+([$'\n\t '])}"
        varname="${varname%%+([$'\n\t '])}"
        if [[ "$varname" ]]; then
            varname="${varname%%+(;)};"
        fi
    done

    # Now finished with extglob.
    if [[ "$unset_extglob" ]]; then shopt -u extglob; fi

    type="$(type -t "$command")"
    case "$type" in
        alias)
            printf "bashwrap doesn't (yet) know how to handle aliases\n" >&2
            return 69  # EX_UNAVAILABLE
            ;;
        keyword)
            printf 'bashwrap cannot wrap Bash keywords\n' >&2
            return 64  # EX_USAGE
            ;;
        builtin|file)
            eval "$command () { $beforecode command $command \"\$@\"; $aftercode }"
            ;;
        function)
            # Keep generating function names until we get to one that doesn't
            # exist.  This allows a function to be wrapped multiple times; the
            # original function will always have the name
            # _bashwrapped_0_<name>.
            n=0
            innerfuncname="_bashwrapped_${n}_$command"
            while declare -Fp -- "$innerfuncname" &>/dev/null; do
                innerfuncname="_bashwrapped_$((++n))_$command"
            done

            # Define a new function with the new function name and the old function
            # code.
            innerfunccode="$(declare -fp -- "$command")"
            eval "${innerfunccode/#$command /$innerfuncname }"

            # Redefine the existing function to call the new function, in
            # between the wrapper code.
            eval "$command () { $beforecode $innerfuncname \"\$@\"; $aftercode }"
            ;;
        '')
            printf 'Nothing called %q found to wrap\n' "$command" >&2
            return 64  # EX_USAGE
            ;;
        *)
            printf 'Unexpected object type %s\n' "$type" >&2
            return 70  # EX_SOFTWARE
            ;;
    esac
}
```

The example in the original question can then be achieved as:

```bash
$ bashwrap foo '' 'echo bar'
$ foo
foo
bar
```

The empty string in the second argument to `bashwrap` is to indicate there's no code to be run *before* the original `foo` function.

You can use `type` to see what's happening under the covers:

```bash
$ foo () { echo "foo"; }
$ type foo
foo is a function
foo ()
{
    echo "foo"
}
$ bashwrap foo '' 'echo "bar"'
$ type foo
foo is a function
foo ()
{
    _bashwrapped_0_foo "$@";
    echo "bar"
}
$ type _bashwrapped_0_foo
_bashwrapped_0_foo is a function
_bashwrapped_0_foo ()
{
    echo "foo"
}
```